# Is it possible to annotate lambda in scala?

Tags: scala, annotations, dsl

For my dsl I need something in the spirit of:

```
@deprecated def foo(x: Int) = x
```

... only for lambdas\anonymous functions.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this exists in the language according to the [lang spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html):

> An annotation of an expression e appears after the expression e,
>   separated by a colon.

So this supposed to work:

```
object TestAnnotation {
  val o = Some(1)

  def f = o.map(_ + 1 : @deprecated("gone", "forever"))

  val e = { 1 + 2 } : @deprecated("hmm", "y")

  println(f)
  println(e)
}
```

However, when I compile it with `scalac -deprecation` I get no warnings whatsoever. I opened an issue [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9654) and got a response that it's not supported.

One workaround you could use is to declare lambda separately:

```
object TestAnnotation {
  val o = Some(1)

  @deprecated("this", "works") val deprecatedLambda: Int => Int = _ + 1

  o.map(deprecatedLambda)
}
```

`scalac` then gives:

```
Annotation.scala:6: warning: value deprecatedLambda in object TestAnnotation is deprecated: this
  o.map(deprecatedLambda)
        ^
one warning found
```